# Heuristic function for A* Dijkstra algorithm with boost graph library

Tags: boost, graph, a-star

I have no much detailed knowledge about A* Dijkstra algorithm. I know it is also a shortest path algorithm which also considers h(x) heuristic along with g(x). I am using Boost Graph Library for my project and there is A* algorithm in the library.

Can anybody show me with a simple example to define a heuristic for a simple undirected graph? It would be of great help to me in moving further.

Answer (score 0):

Without having an example implemented, a heuristic for A* is something like "I know that the path has at least this leghth (and not shorter)". An example would be a map where the road distance between two nodes cannot be shorter than the aerial distance (or Euclidean distance or whatever coordinate system you use). So an example for a heuristic function would be a function returning the aerial distance between two nodes.